# Silverlight binding to method with parameters

Tags: silverlight, binding, parameters

How do i bind a rectangle to a method with parameters?

this is my XAML:

```
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ie:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="SettingMouseEnter"  />
            </i:EventTrigger>
```

And my method:

```
    public void SettingMouseEnter()
    {
        MouseState(true, "setting");
    }
```

But i want to be able to pass parameters from my XAML code to the method, so that i can input true and "setting" as parameters in the XAML code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read, you can't pass anything other than what you are trying. There was another question like this in stack overflow [Is there a way to pass a parameter (or multiple params) to the CallMethodAction behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073065/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-parameter-or-multiple-params-to-the-callmethodaction) take a look at that.

Comment: but in that example what is beeing passed?

Comment: In the example, it is passing, a UI element's (filterbox) text binding.

Comment: In case if you are interested in passing multiple values through command parameter then it gets tricky. One of my suggestion in that case would be, have UI Elements bound to VM and pass only the one critical one you need in the command parameter and then in the command method, read the values that are already bound to VM which should be already in its latest state and use it for your method execution. Hope it make sense.