# WPF Interactions CallMethodAction for DataTemplate in ListCheckBox thrown a exception "Could not find method on object of type"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I'm trying to use interactions, but I can't write ordered params in my method in ViewModel. I'm use a ListBox who have items inner a checkbox and another controls. So I trying to use the different combinations of params TargetObject of CallMathodAction in my usercontrol, but I can't get the object of Item from my ListBox, when CheckBox is 'unchecked'.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Name="PropertiesListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding PropertiesItems}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPropertyItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                               <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction  MethodName="PropertyUnchecked"
                                        TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Item.FieldsProperty.Name}"
                                   Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                            <Path Width="20" 
                                  Height="20" 
                                  Stretch="Fill" 
                                  Fill="{DynamicResource CommonBorderButtonBorderMouseOnBrush}" 
                                  Data="{StaticResource NextBtnGeometry}" />
                        </Canvas>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**C#**
**[0]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

When I try to used the code as described above, I've got a some exception:
Thrown:

> "**Could not find method named 'PropertyChecked' on object of type 'CheckedListItem 1' that matches the expected signature."**(System.ArgumentException)
>   Exception Message = "Could not find method named 'PropertyChecked' on object of type 'CheckedListItem`1' that matches the expected signature.", Exception Type = "System.ArgumentException", Exception WinRT Data = null

From the message, I think, that the C# method have a bad inputs params, I know that Item in ListBox have object of type CheckedListItem<TProperty> and I'm begin to to try different combinations of C# and Xaml code:

**[1]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(CheckedListItem<TProperty>tr, object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

**[2]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

**[3]**

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unchecked");
}
```

**[4]**

```
<CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="PropertyUnchecked"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName = "PropertiesListBox", Path = "DataContex"}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

The Xaml [4] worked with C# methods [0],[2] and [3], but when I debug to know what the sender I have, I've got the only CheckBox like element but I need get the object of type CheckedListItem <TProperty>.

I'm found how to do something like this with a Command mechanism, but I want to use only CallMethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ((ContentPresenter)((CheckBox)e.Source).TemplatedParent).Content as CheckedListItem<TProperty>;
}
```

**Edit**

Passing parameters to `PropertyUnchecked` (e.g. `PropertyUnchecked(object customParam, object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`) was not as easy as I expected because `CallMethodAction` is very strict on certain signatures and does not allow other formats. There are already [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23754678/1648849) provided for this issue however IMO none of them is suitable here.

The only workaround I could think of was to bind the custom parameter to a more accessible item e.g. `CheckBox.Tag` like below:

```
                <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Tag="{Binding}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction  MethodName="PropertyUnchecked" 
                                TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
```

This will send the custom data along with `sender` to the `PropertyUnchecked` method, making the access easier:

```
public void PropertyUnchecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var Item = ((CheckBox)sender).Tag as CheckedListItem<TProperty>;
}
```

Sorry but this was as close as I could get to answer your question, maybe there are better answers out there.

Comment: Thank you very much! That really work for me. 
But, maybe you know what thе params ordered for another TargetObject or you know where I can read something about that? 
Because I search the answer 3 days and read many sources and nothing find about different input arguments for methods like this =(

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will wait your comment, it's very interesting and important for me and other people.

Comment: Sorry It took so long

Comment: Don't worry about time, the solution is most important thing. So I think this way in edit much better first issue, because It is less than operations of conversions.
Thank you very much for this solutions, I will try to use the method with 3 parameters and if this will work I'll write this solution.